# Spring-Neo4j Relation Level

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Assume that I am implementing a user friend relationship on `Neo4j`. I am using `spring-neo4j` for modeling.

Users are related to each other as friend. We can take a users friends and this is `first level relationship`. Is there a way to take friends friends which is `second level relationship` and `third level relationship` in `Neo4J`, especially `spring-neo4j`?.

Thank You!

## Edited:

Could relation level be given dynamically? I have a piece that find every one on all levels.

```
MATCH u1-[:friend*]->(u2) 
WHERE u1.userId IN ["userId1"] 
RETURN u2
```

My edited question is that can I just give a relation level and get the result. For example, I am giving 2 and trying to get 2nd level friends. If I gave 3 it should return 3th level friends. Could this be dynamically give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what is the specific question here but this is how you could do that using spring-data-neo4j

```
@NodeEntity
public class User
{
 @RelatedTo(type="FRIEND")
 Set<User> friends;

 private Iterable<Person> friends;

  @Query(value = "start n=node({self}) match (u)-[r]->(friend)-[r]->(friendOfFriend) where   r.type = 'FRIEND' return friendOfFriend")
 Iterable<User> friendsOfFriends;
}
```

Comment: I edited the question could you check it do you have an answer for the edited part ?

Comment: I found what I looked for.

Answer (score 0):

Anwser of edited part of my question is ;

```
MATCH u1-[:friend*relationLevel]->(u2) 
WHERE u1.userId IN ["userId1"] 
RETURN u2
```

`relationLevel` is the level that I want. If it is 2, result will be only for 2nd level relation.

And it is probably in spring,

```
@Query("start user1=node({0}) match (user1)-[r:friend*{1}]->(user2) where has(user2.userId) return user2.userId")
Iterable<String> getRelatedUserIdsByRelationLevel(GraphUser graphUser,int relationLevel);
```